# List files that have been modified for the last x days, excluding today

Tags: bash, time, find

This lists the files that have been modified for the last day (24 hours), `-mtime -1`, that contain the string "UGW", `-name '*UGW*'`, in their name:

```
find ./ -mtime -1 -type f -name '*UGW*' -printf '%Tc %p\n' | sort
```

Is there an easy way to modify this so that I only list the last X days but exclude today?

**Note:**
I am sorting here, but I do not think this is sorting 100% correctly by timestamp.

**EDIT1** based on anser below getting the below error

```
:~/tmp$ find ./ -mtime -1 -type f -name '*' -printf '%Tc %p\n'                                                                    Tue 08 Mar 2016 12:25:01 NZDT ./compareKPIs-log
    Mon 07 Mar 2016 18:05:02 NZDT ./log-file
    Tue 08 Mar 2016 12:25:01 NZDT ./compareKPIs-error
    Mon 07 Mar 2016 18:05:02 NZDT ./backup_public_html_20160307.tgz


:~/tmp$ comm -13 <(find ./ -daystart -mtime -1 -type f   -printf '%Tc %p\n' ) <(find ./ -daystart -mtime -3 -type f   -printf '%Tc %p\n' )
    Sun 06 Mar 2016 18:05:00 NZDT ./backup_public_html_20160306.tgz
    comm: file 2 is not in sorted order
    Mon 07 Mar 2016 18:05:02 NZDT ./log-file
    comm: file 1 is not in sorted order
    Mon 07 Mar 2016 18:05:02 NZDT ./backup_public_html_20160307.tgz
```

Comment: What do you mean by "today"? "Since midnight"? And "last X days", is that "now times 24 hours", or calendar days?

Comment: when I say last x day I mean, for 1 day would be all of yesterday, for 2 days would be the last 2 days up to midnight yesterday, starting at 00:00 on 2days ago i.e. that would be 48 hours....etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT: The actual way to do this:

```
find ./ -daystart -mtime -3 -type f  ! -mtime -1  -printf '%Tc %p\n'
```

Uses:

- `! -mtime -1` to exclude today
- `-daystart` to start at 00:00

---

Really hackish, but what about

```
comm -13 <(find ./ -daystart -mtime -1 -type f   -printf '%Tc %p\n' | sort) <(find ./ -daystart -mtime -3 -type f   -printf '%Tc %p\n' | sort)
```

The command line options for `comm` are:

```
-1 suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)

-2 suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)

-3 suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
```

Comment: @HattrickNZ This should only be a comment here, not an edit to the question.

Comment: Sorted each find command, that should fix the errors. Also added the actual way to do this.